# Simple access query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a query in Access.

Let's say, for example, I have four fields: Numbers 1-26, Letters A-Z, 26 Names, and 26 Cities, so one record might be: 2, B, Jane, New York

I want to create and save a new query with:
the numbers field, the letters field, and the names field. I want the letters field to be filtered on "A" or "B", and the names field to have an expression so it's always 0.

This will become a loop, so it'll create 13 queries (A/B, C/D, etc).

It seems like having this process in VBA as opposed to the Access macro builder would be better since not only do I have to loop this process, but there are also 2 similar tables (same field names, different values) that I need to run it on.

Comment: I don't think you want to create multiple queries. You want to create a single query and use the macro/VBA to run it with multiple input parameters.

Comment: Use the query design window to create the query, then add parameters on the criteria line, eg : `[enter a number: ]` See if you are getting what you want, then move on to a more advanced approach, such as using a form for the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can run your queries in VBA using a recordset and then work with the data from there:

```
Sub YourQueries(ByVal pstrCol1 As String, ByVal pstrCol2 As String, ByVal pstrCol3 As String, ByVal pstrCol4 As String)
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

' Change types above to match what's actually in the table

strSQL = "SELECT YourColumn1, YourColumn2, YourColumn3, YourColumn4 "
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE "
strSQL = strSQL & "YourColumn1='" & pstrCol1 & "'"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND YourColumn1='" & pstrCol1 & "'"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND YourColumn1='" & pstrCol1 & "'"
strSQL = strSQL & " AND YourColumn1='" & pstrCol1 & "'"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
While Not rs.EOF
    For i = 0 To 3
     Debug.Print rs.Fields(i) & " is Column" & Format(i)
    Next i
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```